# How to update an existing List of object from json using Jackson API

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a list of object that I want update.
Basically I have created my object using spring but the content of the object is empty.

I want to update the List of objects from a json file using Jackson parser.

The json file is compatible with the object. that means that I am letting the mapper to auto-detect the setters.

What happening is that the mapper is loading the object to the list as
As LinkedHashMap object and not as My object

This is my json

```
    [
    {
        "startDate":"01/06/2014 08:00",
        "endDate":"01/06/2014 16:00",
        "shiftType":"Regular",
        "capacity":5
    },
    {
        "startDate":"01/06/2014 16:00",
        "endDate":"01/06/2014 23:00",
        "shiftType":"Regular",
        "capacity":5
    },
    {
        "startDate":"01/06/2014 23:00",
        "endDate":"02/06/2014 08:00",
        "shiftType":"Regular",
        "capacity":5
    },
    {
        "startDate":"02/06/2014 08:00",
        "endDate":"02/06/2014 16:00",
        "shiftType":"Regular",
        "capacity":5
    },
]
```

this is my object

```
    package il.co.shiftsgenerator.engine.model;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class ShiftConfiguration {

    private int capacity;
    private String shiftType;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }
    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(String startDate) throws ParseException {
        dateFormat.parse(startDate);
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(String endDate) throws ParseException {
        dateFormat.parse(endDate);
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }
    public String getShiftType() {
        return shiftType;
    }
    public void setShiftType(String shiftType) {
        this.shiftType = shiftType;
    }
    public SimpleDateFormat getDateFormat() {
        return dateFormat;
    }
    public void setDateFormat(SimpleDateFormat dateFormat) {
        this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ShiftConfiguration [capacity=" + capacity + ", shiftType="
                + shiftType + ", startDate=" + startDate + ", endDate="
                + endDate + "]";
    }

}
```

this is how I am trying to load the data

```
    ObjectMapper  mapper = new ObjectMapper();
InputStream stream =  fileLoaderHelper.getFileAsStream(SHIFT_CONFIG_LIST_JSON_FILE);
List<ShiftConfiguration> shiftBeans = new ArrayList<ShiftConfiguration>();      

for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    ShiftConfiguration shiftBean = context.getBean(ShiftConfiguration.class);
    shiftBeans.add(shiftBean);
}

ObjectReader readerForUpdating = mapper.readerForUpdating(shiftBeans);
readerForUpdating.readValues(stream);
System.out.println(shiftBeans);
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be detecting the correct object due to your date format. I would try explicitly telling Jackson the format for your datetimes and maybe that will straighten things out. Try something like

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
mapper.setDateFormat(df);
```

Before your mapper.readerForUpdating call and see if that does it.

Comment: The mapper is not my object its a the jackson api object.

Comment: Correct, you can see there is a setDateFormat for that object here https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html

Comment: This is not the case . By the why for 1 object it working . The date is String not formmater

Comment: So for one object it is correctly casting as your object, then all the rest are improperly casted as a LinkedHashMap? If so can you paste the one that is working with several that are not?

Comment: This is a problem of type safety in jackson . I know that for a fact . Still not working

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not specifying actual type to use: you are reading `List` of `ShiftConfiguration`, but you are not specifying type. Jackson has no idea what the expected type is: you are just handing it an object to update, and due to Java Type Erasure, `List`s do not have runtime generic type information.

So you'd need to create `readerFor(new TypeRefererence<List<ShiftConfiguration>>() { })` and then the method to indicate you want to update `List`.

Alternatively you might just want to read the new list, giving type information needed, and concatenate manually with `addAll(...)`.

Comment: I can not do it apparently.

I tried to construct the following reader but it didn't work
JavaType t = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(new TypeReference<List<ShiftConfiguration>>() {});

mapper.readerForUpdating(shiftBeans).withType(t)

Still not working

Comment: @MosheTsabari and by not working, you see... `LinkedHashMap` instances getting added or?

Comment: @MosheTsabari I'm sorry but that's not of any help. What do you get? Exception, wrong object? Original object with no change? Your JVM crashing & OS locking up?